Increase the entropy of a simulation box
I've prepared a simulation box in tleap with a solvent different from water.
The molecules of solvent are not randomly arranged, but packed in a ordered manner around the single molecule of solute, also with a lot of voids.
I suppose the ideal phase of equilibration shoud be quite different from most used ones.
Any advice for conducting a balancing phase with a physical sense or to solve the problem of tleap?
